# about new and delete operators over Struct

Tags: c++, memory-management, new-operator, delete-operator

I've a struct

```
#ifndef EVENT_H
#define EVENT_H
struct Event {
int ID;
int num;
int * energies;
};
#endif
```

and a function that works with an Event struct,

```
#include <fstream>
#include "Event.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
Event * read(std::ifstream& os, Event * ev)
{
if(os.fail()) return NULL;
os >> ev->ID >> ev->num;
ev->energies = new int[ev->num];
if(ev->ID!=0 && ev->num!=0){
for (int i = 0; i < ev->num; ++i)
{
os >> * (ev->energies+i);
}
}   
return ev;
}
```

And this is the main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "Event.h"
using namespace std;
Event * read(ifstream& os, Event * ev);
void dump(const Event& ev);
void clear(Event * ev);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
ifstream os(argv[1]);
Event * ev = new Event;
cout << "Created " << ev << endl;
Event * pointer=read(os, ev);

while(pointer!=NULL)
{
dump(*ev);
clear(ev);
Event * ev = new Event;
pointer = read(os,ev);
}
return 0;
}
```

My question is: why, in this case, isn't the memory deallocated(allocated in read() with `ev->energies = new int[ev->num];`) at every  end-calling of read() function?

Comment: Because you need are allocating on heap using `new` operator and you need to de-allocate it using `delete`. Am I missing something here ?

Comment: Ok, i know. My question is why.

In the following code

    `int read(ifstream& os, int *array)
    {
     int i=0;
     int ID=0;
     int num=0;
     os >> ID >> num;
     array = new int[num];
     
     if(ID==0 || num==0) return -1; 
     for (int i = 0; i < 200; ++i)
     {
      *(array+i)=0;
     }
    
     while(i<num)
     {
      os>>*(array+i);
      i++;
     }
     return num;
    }`

After `return num` the array is deleted. What's the difference? Here int * array it's simply a pointer.

Comment: What makes you think the array is being deleted? You are overwriting the pointer so outside this function what you are referring to as *array is still the same. See what happens if you return array instead of num.

Answer (score 2):

No, the memory isn't deallocated. At the end of the function, You need to call

```
delete [] ev->energies
```

Answer (score 0):

You are under the impression that the allocated pointer will be deleted when it goes out of scope. That is not true. It will leak memory. This example will highlight what you are missing in the code you gave in your comment:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int* read(int *array)     {
        int i=0;
        int num=200;
        array = new int[num];
        cout << "Newly allocated pointer " << array << endl;
        if(num==0) return NULL;
        while(i<num) {
                array[i] = i*i;
                i++;
        }
        return array;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  int *ptr;

  cout << "Original pointer address " << ptr << endl;
  int *n = read(ptr);
  cout << "Last value in allocated pointer " << n[199] << endl;
  cout << "Allocated pointer address " << n << endl;
  cout << "Original pointer address " << ptr << endl;
  // following line can cause a segmentation fault
  // cout << "Last value in original pointer (actually garbage) " << ptr[199] << endl;
  delete[] n; // really should delete it
}
```

The *array in read() is passed by value, so changing it will be of local scope.